# Import PDF to Excel, not Embed

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I would like to display PDF in an excel sheet, is this possible?
I don't want to embed the file I want to see the file in a sheet.

I know one can generate a pdf report with excel sheets, but I want to be able to input pages of PDF's into excel.

Comment: Using something like Techsmith's SnagIt you could grab the image and paste it into Excel.

Comment: Or just screenshot each page

Comment: hey guys thanks for your reply, I actually want to automate it so I dont have to screen shot it , with VBA.. Just load it somehow in excel.. Dont worry i tried making a thread with the stackoverflow guys, they down voted me lol.

Comment: " Dont worry i tried making a thread with the stackoverflow guys, they down voted me lol." - they probably had good reason to do so. It seems like you expect us to do your job. Asking for complete code is off-topic in every stakexchange site. You can start learning to write macros and if you've done some part of it we'll be happy to help you with specific questions.

Comment: Thanks Mate. I just dont think its possible to import actual pdf pages to excel sheets, I thought someone on stack might have known.

Comment: No there is no such functionality of excel to automate taking and inserting screenshots. Your comment suggested you're looking for somebody to write the macro for you.

Comment: No I just want to know if its possible to do a vba code that can import a pdf to excel. I dont want screen shot code.

Comment: two ways that I can think of 
1: Convert PDF to JPG and bulk import them to Excel.
2: Convert PDF to EXCEL and edit the file to fit your needs.
Both options can be achieved easily with a program called NitroPDF

Comment: @IbrahimHassan , thanks, is there any free software?

Comment: You can use the trial version for 30 days, I am sure there are lots of other options but you will have to test them separately for each file since they give different results ( in case of converting pdf to excel )